# JS - Как получить случайным образом объект из json-а?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть JSON вида:

```
{
    "10120": {
        "id":  "10120",
        "resultString": "арра",
        "resultImg": " img"
    },
    "10121": {
        "id":  "10121",
        "resultString": "прпрп",
        "resultImg": ""
    },
    "10122": {
        "id":  "10122",
        "resultString": "прпрп",
        "resultImg": ""
    }
}
```

Как получить случайным образом отсюда объект?

Делаю так. Но у меня выводится только название свойства:

```
var res = Object.keys(businesses);
const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(businesses).length);

return res[randNum];
```

Comment: `businesses[res[randNum]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var businesses = {
  "10120": {
    "id": "10120",
    "resultString": "арра",
    "resultImg": " img"
  },
  "10121": {
    "id": "10121",
    "resultString": "прпрп",
    "resultImg": ""
  },
  "10122": {
    "id": "10122",
    "resultString": "прпрп",
    "resultImg": ""
  }
}

function getRandomProperty(aParent) {
  if (aParent) {
    var res = Object.keys(aParent);
    if (res.length > 0) {
      var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.length);
      return aParent[res[randNum]];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(getRandomProperty(businesses));
console.log(getRandomProperty(businesses));
console.log(getRandomProperty(businesses));

console.log(getRandomProperty({}));
console.log(getRandomProperty(null));
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас res - это массив названий полей. Вы берете из него по индексу название поля. А надо брать из объекта, а не из массива res.

```js
let businesses = {
      "10120": {
        "id":  "10120",
        "resultString": "арра",
        "resultImg": " img"
    },
    "10121": {
        "id":  "10121",
        "resultString": "прпрп",
        "resultImg": ""
    },
    "10122": {
        "id":  "10122",
        "resultString": "прпрп",
        "resultImg": ""
    }
};

const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() *  Object.keys(businesses).length);

console.log(businesses[Object.keys(businesses)[randNum]]);
```